# Does this linear operator tends to zero?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $X$ separable Hilbert space with basis $\{e_n\}$, $U_N=\{e_1,...e_N \} \subset X$, $P_N$ the projection operator over $U_N$. Define $Q_N=I-P_N$ the orthogonal complement ($I$ identity) and $B \colon X \to X$ compact linear operator.

I want to prove that $$\lim_{N \to \infty}||BQ_N||= 0$$
I would proceed in the following way:
For every $x \in X$ we have $P_N x \to x$ as $N \to \infty$. Then $Q_N x \to 0$ so that $BQ_N x \to 0$. Now since $B$ is compact we have that the set  $$\overline{B Q_N \{ x \in X: |x|=1\}}=B Q_N \{ x\in X: |x|=1\} $$ is compact. This should imply that the convergence $BQ_N x \to 0$ is uniform in $\{x \in X, |x|=1 \}$, i.e. $$\sup_{|x|=1} |B Q_Nx| \to 0$$
which implies my claim. How do I justify the uniform convergence in $\{x \in X, |x|=1 \}$ ?

Comment: There is a general theorem: if a sequence of operators $A_n$ tends to $0$ pointwise (strongly) and $B$ is a compact operator then $\|A_nB\|\to 0.$ In your case of Hilbert space and $Q_n$ we have $\|BQ_n\|=\|Q_nB^*\| \to 0$ as $Q_n$ tends to $0$ pointwise and $B^*$ is compact.

Comment: Hi thanks, can you please give me a reference for this theorem? @RyszardSzwarc

Comment: I am unable to find it on the net. I am sure you can find it in many textbooks. The proof could go like this. Assume by contradiction $$\|A_{n_k}B\|\ge 2\varepsilon>0.$$ Call $C_k=A_{n_k}.$ There exist $x_k$, $\|x_k\|=1,$ such that $\|C_kBx_k\|>\varepsilon$. Then $Bx_k$ has convergent subsequence. With no loss of generelity we may assume that $Bx_k\to y.$ Thus $$\varepsilon <\|C_kBx_k\|\le \|C_ky\|+\|C_k(Bx_k-y)\|\le |C_ky\|+a\|Bx_k-y)\|$$ where $a=\sup \|A_n\|.$ The RHS tends to $0,$ a contradiction.

Comment: very clear, many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if having infinitely many compact sets leads to a nice argument. Below I can show you two ways of going about this.

It is easier to prove that $Q_NB\to0$. This is enough, because we can then get $Q_NB^*\to0$ and take adjoints.

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. The compactness of $\overline{\{ Bx : |x|=1\}}$ (you cannot remove the closure, in general the range of a bounded operator is not closed) allows you to choose  $\{Bx_1,\ldots,Bx_m\}$, with $|x_k|=1$ for all $k$, such that for all $x$ with $|x|=1$ you have $k\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$ with  $$\|Bx-Bx_k\|<\varepsilon/2.$$
Since $Q_NBx_k\to0$ for $k=1,\ldots,m$, there exists $N_0$ such that $\|Q_NBx_k\|<\varepsilon/2$ for all $N\geq N_0$. Then
$$
\|Q_NBx\|\leq\|Q_NBx-Q_NBx_k\|+\|Q_NBx_k\|\leq\|Bx-Bx_k\|+\frac\varepsilon2<\varepsilon. 
$$
So $\|Q_NB\|<\varepsilon$ for all $N\geq N_0$.

The second way is to use that $B=\lim B_n$, with $B_n$ finite rank. Since $B_nQ_N$ is finite rank, convergence in a ball is uniform due to being in a finite-dimensional space. So $B_nQ_N\xrightarrow{N\to\infty}0$. Then
$$
\|BQ_N\|\leq\|(B-B_n)Q_N\|+\|B_nQ_N\|\leq\|B-B_n\|+\|B_nQ_N\|. 
$$
Thus
$$
\limsup_N\|BQ_N\|\leq\|B-B_n\|,
$$
and as $n$ is arbitrary we get that $\lim_N\|BQ_N\|$ exists and is zero.

Comment: Nice answer. Do you mean $\lim_{N\to \infty} B_nQ_N =0$ and not $B_n$?

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for noticing!